# How to use variable string in a loop?

Tags: c++, string, image, loops, graphics

I have written a program in which I save an image during a loop, with this command

```
 writeimagefile("f:\\chkng\\otp.bmp",0,0,scn,scn);
```

This command is from `graphics.h`, which writes the image file in the given location. How should I save the image every loop with a different name? i.e otp1.bmp, otp2.bmp, otp3.bmp.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: c++ language in devC++.

Comment: What parameters is `writeimagefile` expecting? What **exactly** are their types?

Comment: 'void writeimagefile(
    const char* filename=NULL,
    int left=0, int top=0, int right=INT_MAX, int bottom=INT_MAX,
    bool active=true, HWND hwnd=NULL
    );'
this is full command from its library. but it is executed as i have written in my question. but the problem is how to save with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = start; i != end; ++i )
{
   char filename[100];
   sprintf(filename, "f:\\chkng\\otp%d.bmp", i);
   writeimagefile(filename,0,0,scn,scn);
}
```

Comment: please explain what sprintf means?
and any other way than sprintf, because i an bit familiar with sprintf.

Comment: @Bilal, `sprintf` is like `printf`. `printf` prints to a terminal/console. `sprintf` prints to a string. In this case, it prints to `filename`.

Comment: `@Bilal, `%d` is the format use to write an integer. You can get more about format specifications for `printf` at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I'm assuming that your loop is index based (counts from 0 to a max). I'm also assuming that you've included `string`.

```
int max = 1; //example
for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
   std::string filename = "f:\\chkng\\otp" + std::to_string(i) + ".bmp";
   writeimagefile(filename.c_str(),0,0,scn,scn);
}
```

Explanation:

What I'm doing here is using a loop, building a string with a number in the filename as requested, and calling your function with the `c_str` version (what your function wants) of the filename we just built.

Comment: why cant i use 
       writeimagefile(filename,0,0,scn,scn);

Comment: @Bilal Because your function is expecting a variable of type `char *`, not `string`. The `c_str()` function allows the newer C++ `string` type to be used with code like your function that wants an array of `char`s

Comment: Do note that `"f:\\chkng\\otp" + i + ".bmp"` will not compile

Comment: @NathanOliver You're totally correct, I've added something to make it work. The accepted answer is likely better regardless, but at least this should compile now. I'm not sure what historic things made me think that was valid then. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For loops work well for counting things, and in many languages the example you're showing can be done by concatenating the count into the filename string.  Try something like the following:

```
for (int count = startingNumber; count <= endingNumber; count++)
{
   writeimagefile("f:\\chkng\\otp" + count + ".bmp",0,0,scn,scn);
}
```

Comment: invalid operands of types `const char*' and `const char[5]' to binary `operator+'